# How do I set Windows programs to open with Wine as opposed to Mono?

Tags: wine, mono

Instead of opening with Wine, windows programs are opening with Mono. I could fiddle around using my knowledge of the system but I'd rather not.

What do I need to do to get things back to normal?

#### Update:

I forgot to mention the first time, but Wine doesn't show up in the list.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To set the default application for a specific file type, locate a file of that type in the file manager, right-click it, and select Properties. Click the Open With tab and select the application you want to use for that file type. Use the Set as default button to make the application the default application.

Comment: I forgot to mention, wine doesn't show up in the list and there seems to be no way to add it.

Comment: you can see if the application/program shows up in  "sudo update-alternatives --all"

Comment: I checked, and it does not.